# What does :: (double-colon) mean before an assignment in lua?

Tags: lua, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I am currently looking through the first page of documentation for LUA and noticed that every assignment appears as `var ::= Name`, however I could not find any reference to the syntax of `::=` itself. The documentation goes over the structuring of an assignment but glosses over these symbols. What I want to know is if every assignment requires the `::` before the actual assignment operator, and, if so, why is it structured this way and not just a plain `=`?

Comment: `Here is the complete syntax of Lua in extended BNF` (c)Lua manual.  See [BNF description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is not Lua code, but a fragment of the grammar of the Lua language, as defined in [Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). The `::=` operator is part of BNF.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I wish there was some way to tell what are BNF symbols and what is not without knowing all the symbols in the first place. Perhaps they should bold/italicize or something.

Answer (score -1):

It's the assignment operator - typically used in formal grammars.